# multivariate LSTM for varying sequence length and varying Batch size

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I receive data from a sensor and after some preprocessing, I get data points (1-18) with 8 features in every for-loop. That is, in one for-loop I get data of size *10x8* points while in the 2nd run, I get *18x8*. where [10,18] represents the number of data-points while 8 are the number of features and so on. The number of data-points differs in every for-loop run. To make it stable I padded zeros where it is less than 15 and ignore the data points if the count is more than 15. (for above two runs, data became 15x8 and 15x8)

**Training Data set:** I have a data set from 20 measurements file and each file has the different batch size(number of training data). Every File has a different time duration. Let's say if one cycle is 1 sec. One file ran for 384 sec while another for 500 sec.

***What I did:***
I am using multivariate LSTM with labels **0** and **1** to do binary classification and padding zeros to get equal sequence data points i.e, from one file `(386,15,8)` while from another file `(1380,15,8)`. In the end, I am giving Keras `input_shape=(15,8)`. The model performance is really bad, I changed many hyper-parameters. Should I avoid zero-padding and give `input_shape=(None,8)` or should I involve batch_size somehow? Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: In order to provide insightful information, could you please provide a subset of your data and/or the implementation of your LSTM?
So we can replicate your results to check possible problems.
In addition, could you please develop more your first explanatory paragraph?, I can barely understand what are you stating.

Comment: Can you check now, I can't share the data but hopefully you will understand now